# C++ multithreading: "terminate called without an active exception" with switch statement

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating a WinAPI application with a switch statement for all of the buttons that I have in the GUI. One particular button is supposed to join a thread and the thread is supposed to start a loop. The code is like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam) {

    //the thread
    std::thread t1(Loop, hwnd);

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        Controls(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        if ((HIWORD(param) == BN_CLICKED) && (lparam != 0))
        {
            switch (LOWORD(param))
            {
                case START_THREAD:
                    MessageBeep(MB_OK);

                    //Join the thread
                    t1.join();

                    break;

                case OTHER_STUFF: 
                 for other buttons that are irrelevant to this post
                 */
            }
        }

        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, param, lparam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am extremely new to multithreading in c++, so I do not understand why this is occuring. However, I had read in other stackoverflow posts that it was terminating itself because of something to do with multithreading. If you could help me out that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that all paths out of the function call `join` on the thread object you created.

Comment: This happens (I believe) when your program terminates with dangling threads that haven't been either joined or detached.

Comment: You are creating a new thread on *every* window message that is received, is that intentional? Or do you want to create the thread only when the window is created, or when a button is pressed, etc?

Comment: This is exactly why [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) was invented.

Comment: If a thread raise an exception, it should handle it or you should use construct that handle it for you. If you are serious about multithreading, then buy **C++ Concurrency in Action** book by **Anthony Williams**.

Comment: A thread should usually not talk to the UI. Thus it is **very suspicious** that you pass an handle to your thread unless the purpose is to do some `PostMessage`. If you want to start the thread in response top a message and stop in respond to another one, then `t1` should be a member of your class and you should use `std::move` to create the object.